# How is a Remote Apprentice Machinist Possible?

Tags: machining, education

I was researching opportunities to learn more about manufacturing and machining and found that much of the education is driven through 3yr-4yr apprenticeships. I found several postings for remote opportunities. How is this possible? How can one get "on-the-job" training with CNC lathes and mills etc. when not physically present? Do you just watch on-demand videos for 8hrs/day?

Comment: ask the company that posted the job

Comment: Anyway yes its possible. What you do is you use CAM software all day long.

Comment: The youtube videos of CNC machines crashing are based on those who studied remote :) and I have two sons who completed precision machinist apprenticeships, including CNC.

Comment: @jsotola - it wasn’t just one company, it was multiple, but I did reach out, was curious more from an industry perspective if it was a standard option and how it worked

Comment: Maybe some of them are also "partially remote", where you can choose to spend X days operating machines and Y days working on CAD files etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts. However, the comment, to contact said companies and ask, is a very good one.

### 1. HR-related

It may be that HR on behalf of its company or client tries to attract students via "remote", who are reluctant due to OR even hindered by Covid-19 infections.

Remember, Covid is "ended politically", not biologically. Cures to complex long-covid are still not found, affecting considerable parts of (previous) employees, students etc., i.e. practically disabling them "forever" at the moment.

### 2. Technology-related

More and more machines have digital interfaces. I.e. as long as you don't have to touch and repair it, you can obtain all data all day long and control it or change its behavior on-line.

You may even be asked to model or simulate wrt to the machine(s), e.g. to solve long lasting problems or to do sth. "innovative". *(to contrast "new to us" - innovative - with inventiveness - "new to the world")*

And yes, there will certainly be training sessions on-line, be it video, presentation, video-conferencing etc.